# SQL Server display only selected text from text with - not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

In the original database the column's row text is like PA-PB-PC and i wanted to select only PB when i execute the select query.

Is there any suggestion for this?

```
Select Section 
from Department
```

Expected solution is to display only the middle text 'PB' when select query is executed

Comment: Is the PB always at the same index? or always after the first -, and before the next one? Suggest you look at substring and possibly charindex

Comment: there are few , for instance: PA-PB-PC, PA-PCA-PZ, PA-PXA-PXX, i have used split("-")(1) in vb.net to make it display the middle text, but when i do the cell merge on text then it not working for PB merge with PB, PCA merge with PCA cause the different  of initial value of third text.

Comment: In future, instead of just providing one example and assuming that we will read your mind, try providing the actual rules the code needs to implement.  For example, you might say "the text contains three substrings delimited by '-' characters and I need to retrieve just the second substring".  It's not difficult to explain such things if you understand them yourself and, if you don't understand them, you probably need to gain that understanding before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a few methods:

**SAMPLE**

```
declare @var varchar(64) = 'PA-PB-PC '

select 
    left(substring(@var,charindex('-',@var) + 1 ,99),charindex('-',substring(@var,charindex('-',@var) + 1 ,99)) - 1)
```

So for your column...

```
select 
    Section = left(substring(Section,charindex('-',Section) + 1 ,99),charindex('-',substring(Section,charindex('-',Section) + 1 ,99)) - 1)
from Department
```

This is based off the statement that you want to display the *middle* text, and your sample has 3 segments.

Another easier method is with `parsename`

```
declare @var varchar(64) = 'PA-PB-PC '

select 
    Section = parsename(replace(@var,'-','.'),2)
```

So for your table:

```
select 
    Section = isnull(parsename(replace(Section,'-','.'),2),Section)
from Department
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your swift response but it doesnt work on my sql server management studio =(

Comment: you need to be more specific @Kit the version of SSMS shouldn't matter.

Comment: ok,i try again, or there is better solution for this scenario? there are few , for instance: PA-PB-PC, PA-PCA-PZ, PA-PXA-PXX, i have used split("-")(1) in vb.net to make it display the middle text, but when i do the cell merge on text then it not working for PB merge with PB, PCA merge with PCA cause the different of initial value of third text.

Comment: the last query in my post would be ideal... unless you are saying those values are all in one row?

Comment: yes, your last query solved my problem, just left another problem which i have one row without the - showed null value.

Comment: and what would you expect this row to show @Kit ? See the edit (rerun my last query)

Comment: it works! thanks alot, by the way can you explain what is this ('-', '.') mean in your last query? is it a replacement of - with .? i dont understand the '.'

Comment: Yes, sorry @Kit , the replace function is replacing all hyphens with periods in the Section column. This is because the outer function parsename requires periods. parsename is actually created to parse server.database.schema.object in that format, but you can use it to parse any 4 elements delimited by a period.

Comment: wait @scsimon, i just realized one thing, for the text contained 3 substrings with - works but for 2 substrings with - for example : PA-PAC become PA instead of PAC, sorry for bothering you again.

Comment: I'm headed our @Kit but you stated *Expected solution is to display only the middle text* and in that situation, there would be no *middle text*. You could use a `case expression` though. I'll update tomorrow.

Comment: sorry for mislooked that and caused inconvenience to you.